# Phototransistor as a pull-down in digital circuit

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, phototransistor, pulldown

I have very little experience with phototransistors. I'm trying to create a circuit that will effectively function as collision detection. I'm using [OPB608A](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnology.ttelectronics.com%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2Fproductdatasheets%2FOPB608.pdf&ei=YgCwULvrGvDJ0AXTzYGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHzkFlSHIWME4F4ZMv8yzOioPC-hA&sig2=jMa61mozLCMmWViSWgPO5w) which utilizes an NPN transistor. My goal is to use said transistor to output logical signal to my [PIC18F4520](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2Fdevicedoc%2F39631e.pdf&ei=4QCwUOSvNoPO0QXT6IGYCA&usg=AFQjCNFyofJLjtujYah4FAKTYn7hhRBn4A&sig2=crUqGDBnvPU2qdEDPLe5VA). The I/O pin I'm using for this has Schmitt Trigger Buffer - according to the datasheet any input above 0.8VDD (~4V) will be treated as logical high (and 0.2VDD - 1V - will bring it back down).

Having very little experience I am tempted to use the following circuit:
[image: circuit]

and adjust value of `R1` to adjust the sensitivity. My question is: is this a good idea? Won't this cause any problems (such as pretty much shorting the circuit if `R1` is low value)? Any better way to handle it?

Comment: Your circuit is fairly common.  I don't see any glaring problems.  It might just work for you.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Thanks! It's really having somebody with experience say it has a chance to work! :)

Comment: consider 10Kohm for now .. The current gain on the reflective sensor is very low.  What object is being used for this>? It is not very sensitive and very close proximity. Is that ok? 1.35 mm gap to reflective surgface hFE= 10%

Comment: Try 1K, 10K, 100K. 1M might work but it's a bit high to drive the PIC input. The best value will depend on the light level. A digital voltmeter and a sheet of black paper are handy!

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, just be careful using the really high resistance values.  100k+ and beyond leaves your circuit more vulnerable to noise injection.  It takes a bit of experimentation like the above responses have indicated.